# Get session cookie from android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-cookiemanager

I'm currently developing a cordova app with an ADFS authentication through inappbrowser.

This works well so far. But I need to retrieve the session cookie stored in the webview instance and be able to use it in another application with the same mechanism, so the user doesn't need to log in twice, as both apps use the same corporate login.

I've tried recovering the cookie with CookieManager

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
```

However, it doesn't list the session cookie. It seems CookieManager doesn't return those cookies without expiration date.
I've been able to successfully terminate the session by running

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookies(null);
```

So I'm sure the session cookie is there, but I'm unable to get/manipulate it.